# Unable to ping my server when locked session

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I installed a new Ubuntu 22.04 as an Apache server. I have 2 DNS name for this server, dns1.name.com and dns2.name.com.

From another computer I can ping it in three ways :

```
ping 10.10.10.1 -> IP address
ping dns1.name.com -> dns1
ping dns2.name.com -> dns2
```

All this ping works well.

If my Ubuntu server goes in lock mode because I don't use mouse or keyboard for minutes, then after a certain amount of time I'm unable to ping it from my another computer with none of the three manners above.

If I open my session on the Ubuntu server, after few seconds I can ping it again on my other computer !

I have no clue on Google to explain and fix this...

Thanx for your help

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop? (They're different ISOs). Is your server connected over WiFi or Ethernet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that system suspend is set after certain period of inactivity?

Please check the sleep/suspend options.

```
systemctl status suspend.target
```

You can mask the related services and see if it fixes the issue.

```
systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: thanx, it seems to be the solution ! I used the Settings GUI, "Power" subcategory and I set the "Automatic suspend" from ON to OFF